# Launch Screen Without image set in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

I have a Launch Screen where I set an UIImageView inside the xib and add constraints for prevent the distortion of the image. In all iOS 8 devices (iphone 4s, iphone 5c, 5s, iphone 6, and 6Plus, and iPads) show correctly, but in iOS 7.1 - 7.2 devices it appear Black... Whats happend?

I'm developing in Xcode 6.2 and Swift

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's only using the `.xib` file file for iOS 8+

For previous versions, you need to specify a launch screen in the images.xcassets catalog.

You can refer to [this blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/) to see how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can directly add the app icons and splash images in the images.xcassets, Click on + button to add the respective image set for iphone5 with iOS 5,6,7 ,iphone4, iPad. now no need to set the images name like default.png,default@2x.png for splash in iOS 7 and using .xib file for iOS 8

Comment: just place 2 images with name default@2x.png and default.png with the sizes of the devices and place them in image.xcassets